# process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, dotenv

I am implementing Stripe in my project and getting this error on the browser:  `` Failed prop type: The prop `stripeKey` is marked as required in `ReactStripeCheckout`, but its value is `undefined`. ``

I'm storing my publishable key in a .env file in the client folder:
`REACT_APP_STRIPE = pk_mykeykey`

And in my component, I've assigned the key to KEY:

`const KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_STRIPE`

And here's my Stripe component:

```
             name="Lama Shop"
             image="https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/1486366?v=4"
             billingAddress
             shippingAddress
             description={`Your total is $${cart.total}`}
             amount={cart.total * 100}
             token={onToken}
             stripeKey={KEY}
            >
              
            <Button>CHECKOUT NOW</Button>
            </StripeCheckout>
```

I've console.logged the key, it returns undefined and the token also returns null.

Comment: did you restart your server after adding variables in `.env` file ?

Comment: i'm glad to know you  fixed it !! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

1. re-starting the node-server again. Environment variables are only handled once in a react-app's lifecycle, which is on startup of the react app server.
2. Make sure your `.env` file is located in the same root directory as your `package.json` file, and if you aren't using `create-react-app`, make sure its included in your build script.
3. If the above steps didn't resolve your issue, you shouldn't need `dotenv` when building a react app, but you can import as such:

```
    import * as dotenv from "dotenv"
    //insert your config file path here
    const configPath = "./path/to/.env"
    const configVariables = dotenv.config(configPath)
    const key = configVariables.REACT_APP_STRIPE
    console.log(key)
```

Comment: restarting the server solved the issue. Interestingly enough, I'd already done that several times and the problem persisted. It worked when I closed VS Code and reopened it after your answer. Thanks!